# which xsd schema for wsdl 1.1 is the right one?

Tags: wsdl

I have found that there is a multitude of XSD files on the web that claim their targetNamespace is "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/". Naturally, there is one at "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/", but there is another one at "http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#A4.1". And e.g. Oracle has at least 10 versions of wsdl.xsd in its SOA Suite 11g, all somehow derived from the xmlsoap.org or w3.org version.

The problem is, all these various WSDL 1.1 definitions are mutually different!! For instance the schema at "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" allows the "name" attribute on  and  for operations in the  sections, while the schema at "http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#A4.1" doesn't allow that.

So, which XSD schema for WSDL 1.1 is the right one?

Comment: I have just found that the XSD version that is part of the specification does not correspond to the specification itself. Because the specification allows @name on <input/output>, see the example in [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_bindings). So, though [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) is the WSDL 1.1 specification, the schema there is unusable. The schema at "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" has this bug fixed already. But is this fixed XSD normative?

Comment: Usually people have `xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/`.